# Japanese Date Format ios

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

ok, straight to the point, i want to make calendar format like this

> YYYY年MM月DD日

i've set my code like this

```
- (void)RecentStartDidSelect:(NSDate *)selectedDate element:(id)element {
    self.selectedDate = selectedDate;
    //////
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]] autorelease]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY(EEE)-MM(EEEm)-dd(EEE)"];

    NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.selectedDate];
    //may have originated from textField or barButtonItem, use an IBOutlet instead of element
    Recent_start.text = theDate;
    [Recent_start resignFirstResponder];

}
```

and the output is

```
 theDate-->2013(Wed)-02(Wed48)-06(Wed)
```

i'm lost now, how to create date format like that? :(( pls help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy年MM月dd日"];
```

That is Chinese

Comment: do that calendar standard of nsdate?

Comment: @AriePrasetyo more infomation you can see this :http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: It actually is not?
At least, according to wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Japan

Answer (score 0):

You may face problems in Chinese and Japanese for missing the word "日"
so the solution that solved this for me was using date formatter templates as below:

```
private enum DateFormatters {

        private static func dateFormat(from template: String, locale: Locale) -> String {
            guard let formatterString = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: template, options: 0, locale: locale)
            else {
                assertionFailureOrLog("Invalid Date Format")
                return ""
            }
            return formatterString
        }

        private static func dateFormater(from template: String) -> DateFormatter {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat(from: template, locale: formatter.locale)

            return formatter
        }

        static let dayAndMonthFormatter = dateFormater(from: "YYYYMMMddE")
    }
```

you can use it like this:

```
let arrivalDate = DateFormatters.dayAndMonthFormatter.string(from: arrivalTime)
```

and below are variant formats that can be used

```
formatdate("Mdyyyy") // "1/2/1984"
formatdate("yyyyMMdd") // "01/02/1984"
formatdate("yyyyMMMdd") // "Jan 02, 1984"
formatdate("yyyyMMMMdd") // "January 02, 1984"
formatdate("yyyyMMMMMdd") // "J 02, 1984"
formatdate("yyyyG") // "1984 AD"
formatdate("yyyyGGGG") // "1984 Anno Domini"
formatdate("yyyyMMMddE") // "Mon, Jan 02, 1984"
formatdate("yyyyMMMddEEEE") // "Monday, Jan 02, 1984"
formatdate("yyyyMMMddEEEEE") // "M, Jan 02, 1984"

formatdate("MdYYYY") // "1/2/1984"
formatdate("YYYYMMdd") // "01/02/1984"
formatdate("YYYYMMMdd") // "Jan 02, 1984"
formatdate("YYYYMMMMdd") // "January 02, 1984"
formatdate("YYYYMMMMMdd") // "J 02, 1984"
formatdate("YYYYG") // "1984 AD"
formatdate("YYYYGGGG") // "1984 Anno Domini"
formatdate("YYYYMMMddE") // "Mon, Jan 02, 1984"
formatdate("YYYYMMMddEEEE") // "Monday, Jan 02, 1984"
formatdate("YYYYMMMddEEEEE") // "M, Jan 02, 1984"
```